# how does mobx achieve its magic

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am curious as to how mobx works under the hood.

If I have a component that is both an observer and contains observables:

```
@observer
export default class Form extends Component {
  @observable submitted = false;

  @action.bound
  submit() {
  }
}
```

How does mobx cause a re-render without using setState or does it use setState?

Comment: [the project is right here for you to dig into](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Comment: Check out the documentation on 'store': https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html

Comment: The accepted answer should be - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64300840/1410291

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254. `@observer` is basically a shorthand for `autorun(() => this.render())` (it is actually a bit more complex, but that is what it conceptualy boils down to)

Comment: I went through your article, but it basically describes the conceptual model, not under the hood workings of mobx (i.e. at JavaScript level). For eg, how does any `observer` component gets notified of changes to `observable`s? Does it use an event based system? Can you mention the pseudo code for that?

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding, mobx defines its observable properties on stores something like this:

```
export const nameObservable = new Observable(observer => {
  Object.defineProperty(customState, "firstName", {
    get: function() {
      return this._firstName.toUpperCase();
    },
    set: function(name) {
      this._firstName = name;
      observer.next(this._firstName);
    }
  });
});

// In your component
nameObservable.subscribe(render)
```

When you execute `customState.firstName = 'New name'` this will call the set method on property and `observer.next` will trigger all methods subscribed to this property... causing update in UI.

Answer (score 3):

To understand how `mobx` works under the hood, check [this repl](https://repl.it/@ludbek/reactive-programming#index.js) out.

I learned about it from one of the videos of @mweststrate and an academic paper from someone. Both of which I cannot find anymore.

Comment: Make TypeScript version of the code https://shorturl.at/jqP45

Answer (score 0):

MobX uses `Object.defineProperty()` to wrap it's own functionality to the assigment operator. When you write something like `form.submitted = false`, in reality a MobX method is called. Also see https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/741633922694586368 and https://x-team.com/blog/es5-object-defineproperty-method/.